# How can I find dictation commands in French?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Apple has a list of dictation commands online here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6482 and here http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6481.

Does anyone know where I can find the French versions?

Comment: do you have French OS X

Comment: Did you download the French extended version? The software needed for each language you select downloads from Apple.

Comment: I downloaded Enhanced Dictation for English (UK) and French (France).  I'm running OS X in English.  I've figured out a few of the commands, like "Switch to (app)" is "Basculer vers (app)".  I'd really like to see a complete list...

Comment: only if someone here has a French OS X !

Answer (score 2):

You can find the list of the default voice commands here: http://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT6482

[image]

You can find the list of the advanced voice commands here: System > Accessibility > Dictation:

[image]

[image]